# Gradient boosting doubts

Tags: gradient-descent, boosting, ensemble-learning

I am new to the concept of Gradient Boosting and i have a few doubts related to it. It will be helpful if some one can explain them.

### 1) Gradient boosting is gradient descent in functional space

[image: Functional Gradient Descent]

As per my understanding the functions in the functional space are the weak learners.
In the diagram above F(x) represents the weak learners and the entire gradient descent is taking place in 2 dimensional plane .

### 2) Why do we train the weak learners on the pseudo reiduals.

Suppose f0(x) is my first initial model. So shouldn't the next model be f1(X) = f0(x) - learning_rate * slope.

But instead we are using f1(x) = f0(x) - learning_rate * weake_learner trained on slope

These are my two doubts . It would be helpful if someone can clear them.

Sources from which i am studying:

1. https://explained.ai/gradient-boosting/
2. https://simple-complexities.github.io/optimization/functional/gradient/descent/2020/03/04/functional-gradient-descent.html
3. https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/gradient-boosting-explained/
4. https://mlcourse.ai/articles/topic10-boosting/

It would be appreciated if someone can explain me the doubts with less maths .
Thanks